# Simple hashmap implementation in C++

Tags: c++, hashmap, hashtable

I'm relatively new to C++. In Java, it's easy for me to instantiate and use a hashmap. I'd like to know how to do it in a simple way in C++, since I saw many different implementations and none of them looked simple to me.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Most compilers should define `std::hash_map` for you; in the coming `C++0x` standard, it will be part of the standard library as [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). The [STL Page](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_map.html) on it is fairly standard. If you use Visual Studio, [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x7w9f6z(VS.71).aspx) has a page on it.

If you want to use your class as the value, not as the key, then you don't need to do anything special. All primitive types (things like `int`, `char`, `bool` and even `char *`) should "just work" as keys in a `hash_map`. However, for anything else you will have to define your own hashing and equality functions and then write "functors" that wrap them in a class.

Assuming your class is called `MyClass` and you have already defined:

```
size_t MyClass::HashValue() const { /* something */ }
bool MyClass::Equals(const MyClass& other) const { /* something */ }
```

You will need to define two functors to wrap those methods in objects.

```
struct MyClassHash {
  size_t operator()(const MyClass& p) const {
    return p.HashValue();
  }
};

struct MyClassEqual {
  bool operator()(const MyClass& c1, const MyClass& c2) const {
    return c1.Equals(c2);
  }
};
```

And instantiate your `hash_map`/`hash_set` as:

```
hash_map<MyClass, DataType, MyClassHash, MyClassEqual> my_hash_map;
hash_set<MyClass, MyClassHash, MyClassEqual> my_hash_set;
```

Everything should work as expected after that.

Comment: I forgot to tell I'm using Unix. The example you coded looks very simple, I'll try it. But the HashValue() method I should create myself, right? Asking that because Java has a default hashcode() method for Object class, I don't know how it works in C++.

Comment: I added some more explanation to the answer. Also, the boost stuff has been recommended as well - it is analagous, but learning (some parts of) boost can be like learning a whole new language. unordered isnt a bad place to start.

Answer (score 16):

Using hashmaps in C++ is easy! It's like using standard C++ map. You can use your's compiler/library implementation of `unordered_map` or use the one provided by [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/unordered.html), or some other vendor. Here's a quick sample. You will find more if you follow the links you were given.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    typedef std::tr1::unordered_map< std::string, int > hashmap;
    hashmap numbers;

    numbers["one"] = 1;
    numbers["two"] = 2;
    numbers["three"] = 3;

    std::tr1::hash< std::string > hashfunc = numbers.hash_function();
    for( hashmap::const_iterator i = numbers.begin(), e = numbers.end() ; i != e ; ++i ) {
        std::cout << i->first << " -> " << i->second << " (hash = " << hashfunc( i->first ) << ")" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [boost.unordered](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/unordered.html), and its [data structure](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/unordered/buckets.html).

Answer (score 3):

Try boost's [unordered](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/unordered.html) classes.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Simple Hash Map (Hash Table) Implementation in C++](https://goo.gl/mgfyZ3) for a basic Hash Table with generic type key-value pairs and separate chaining strategy.