# Using a C/C++ data structure in a C# program

Tags: c#, c++, c, dll, interop

I have a super high-performance C/C++ data structure ([see here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300525/super-high-performance-c-c-hash-map-table-dictionary)) that I'd like to access and use in my C# program.

***Imagine the C/C++ data structure has a public API (`get`, `add`, `delete`, etc). 
How can I call these methods lots of times within C# in a high-performance way?***

***P.S.*** Before you criticize my use of the phrase "C/C++"... 
In my view, C/C++ is distinct from both the C *and* C++ programming languages. I don't know C++, but rather an extension to C that uses some C++ constructs and can be compiled with a C++ compiler!

Comment: I doubt you  will achieve anything faster than what is included in the framework. You will encounter a huge performance hit when you are marshaling between managed and unmanaged code and values.

Comment: `@Daniel A. White:` Yeah, that's what I'm worried about, especially since the map methods get called _lots_ of times. Is that performance hit inevitable? What if I use the `unsafe` keyword in C#?

Comment: Daniel is correct.  You'd do better to just port the collection to C#.  Your C# implementation *could* use `unsafe` but almost certainly does not need to.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm gonna push a bit more code to the C side and minimize the calls that the C# side has to make.

Answer (score 5):

If performance is important to you, then you should avoid crossing the managed/unmanaged boundary "lots of times". Both C# and C++ can be high performance languages but the interop perf costs are not pleasant.

I suggest you write a C library (which could be implemented with C++ constructs as long as the methods are extern C) and call it from the C# code -once!- using P/Invoke. This library can party on your high performance data structure and return some useful information to the C# side.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. I can push a bit more of the C# code into the C part and minimize the calls that I make between them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pipe.