# Choosing between std::map and std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, dictionary, unordered-map

Now that `std` has a real hash map in `unordered_map`, why (or when) would I still want to use the good old `map` over `unordered_map` on systems where it actually exists? Are there any obvious situations that I cannot immediately see?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

As [already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902644/choosing-between-stdmap-and-stdunordered-map/3902650#3902650), `map` allows to iterate over the elements in a sorted way, but `unordered_map` does not. This is very important in many situations, for example displaying a collection (e.g. address book). This also manifests in other indirect ways like: (1) Start iterating from the iterator returned by `find()`, or (2) existence of member functions like `lower_bound()`.

Also, I think there is some difference in the **worst case** *search* complexity.

- For `map`, it is O( lg N )
- For `unordered_map`, it is O( N ) [This *may* happen when the hash function is not good leading to too many hash collisions.]

The same is applicable for **worst case** *deletion* complexity.

Comment: you are right about worst case, but this post is somehow misleading - as on average std::unordered_map is O(1) for search complexity which is much better then std::map

Comment: It is very important to understand that for some applications, worst case performance is crucial to know and is the deciding factor. For some hard real-time systems, having a linear worst case like the hashtable is not acceptable. std::map is always O(lg N), which is a very nice property to have.

Answer (score 98):

In addition to the answers above you should also note that just because `unordered_map` is constant speed (`O(1)`) doesn't mean that it's faster than `map` (of order `log(N)`). The constant may be bigger than `log(N)` especially since `N` is limited by 2<sup>32</sup> (or 2<sup>64</sup>).

So in addition to the other answers (`map` maintains order and hash functions may be difficult) it may be that `map` is more performant.

For example in a program I ran for a [blog post](http://lanzkron.wordpress.com/2010/06/02/optimizing-collatz-for-klutzes/) I saw that for VS10 `std::unordered_map` was slower than `std::map` (although `boost::unordered_map` was faster than both).

[image: Performance Graph]

Note 3rd through 5th bars.

Comment: what is the value of N in this graph?

Comment: @paulm, as I stated in the [blog post](http://lanzkron.wordpress.com/2010/06/02/optimizing-collatz-for-klutzes/) `N=10,000,000`.

Comment: The blog link has gone the way of the dodo, and the results presented here are of little value without that context, as the time needed to hash vs. compare things varies hugely with the exact hash function, data type, length, and values.  That's particularly important with the VC++ Standard Library, as hash functions are fast but collision prone: numbers passed through unaltered, only 10 characters spaced along a string of any length are combined in the hash value, bucket counts aren't prime.  (GNU is at the opposite end of the spectrum).

Comment: @TonyD, the blog post link still works for me.

Comment: VS10, that's your problem right here.

Comment: @n.m. Sadly my time machine wasn't working on Oct 11 2010.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid post. I have found this myself. It's a good example of theory vs reality. In theory a hash map should be faster, but they might actually be slower. Never take for granted what textbooks nor what the "experts" say.
Especially for performance desktop CPUs caching can be a big factor in container algorithms. Theory can be way off from reality.
For when performance really matters profile things yourself and experiment trying the various options. You might be surprised what you find.
Plus there are down to clock cycle profiling tools for most platforms to tune things.

Answer (score 31):

<sub>Partly based on Chandler Carruth's [CppCon 2014 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHNmRkzxHWs).</sub>

`std::map` is (considered by many to be) not useful for performance-oriented work:

- If you want O(1)-amortized access, use a [proper hash-map](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/49853/15631) (which will probably use [open addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Open_addressing)).
- If you want O(1)-amortized access but can't be bothered to get a decent implementation of anything at least use `std::unorderded_map` rather than `std::map`.
- If you want sorted sequential access into your map (which you typically don't), use something based on a vector.

Also, `std::map` is a balanced tree; and you have to traverse it, or re-balance it, incredibly often. These are cache-killer and cache-apocalypse operations respectively... so just say NO to `std::map`.

You might be interested in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3300525/1593077) on efficient hash map implementations.

(PS - `std::unordered_map` is cache-unfriendly because it uses linked lists as buckets.)

Comment: What is a "proper associative array"? What does proper mean here? Isn't an unordered_map an associative array? What is not proper about it?

Comment: @Will: Good point, rephrased and added a link.

Answer (score 22):

I think it's obvious that you'd use the `std::map` you need to iterate across items in the map in sorted order.

You might also use it when you'd prefer to write a comparison operator (which is intuitive) instead of a hash function (which is generally very unintuitive).

Answer (score 14):

Say you have very large keys, perhaps large strings. To create a hash value for a large string you need to go through the whole string from beginning to end. It will take at least linear time to the length of the key. However, when you only search a binary tree using the `>` operator of the key each string comparison can return when the first mismatch is found. This is typically very early for large strings.

This reasoning can be applied to the `find` function of `std::unordered_map` and `std::map`. If the nature of the key is such that it takes longer to produce a hash (in the case of `std::unordered_map`) than it takes to find the location of an element using binary search (in the case of `std::map`), it should be faster to lookup a key in the `std::map`. It's quite easy to think of scenarios where this would be the case, but they would be quite rare in practice i believe.