# Problems using a map with a bitset as a key

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, bitset

I am trying to create a `map` in C++ with `bitset` as a key. However the compiler generates the following error messages

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/string:50:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_classes.h:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/ios_base.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/ios:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/iostream:40,
                 from test2.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_function.h: In member function ‘bool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = std::bitset<8u>]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_map.h:452:2:   instantiated from ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = std::bitset<8u>, _Tp = int, _Compare = std::less<std::bitset<8u> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::bitset<8u>, int> >, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = int, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = std::bitset<8u>]’
test2.cpp:22:30:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_function.h:236:22: error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘__x < __y’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_function.h:236:22: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:207:5: note: template<class _T1, class _T2> bool std::operator<(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h:291:5: note: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator<(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h:341:5: note: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator<(const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2510:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2522:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2534:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const _CharT*, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_tree.h:856:5: note: template<class _Key, class _Val, class _KeyOfValue, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_set.h:713:5: note: template<class _Key, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_multiset.h:696:5: note: template<class _Key, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::multiset<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::multiset<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_map.h:894:5: note: template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_multimap.h:812:5: note: template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
```

The progam code is given below
I am trying to use bitset as a key to a map in C++. However, everytime I run the code below I run into errros.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
#include <set>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    bitset<8> test;
    test = 9;
    cout<<"Set to 9"<<endl;
    map <bitset<8> , int> mymap;
    pair <biset<8> , int> p;
    p.first = test;
    p.second = 9;
    string teststring;
    teststring = test.to_string<char,char_traits<char>,allocator<char> >();
    cout<<teststring<<temymap[test]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use your own comparator class:

```
struct Comparer {
    bool operator() (const bitset<8> &b1, const bitset<8> &b2) const {
        return b1.to_ulong() < b2.to_ulong();
    }
};
/* ... */
map <bitset<8> , int, Comparer> mymap;
```

Note that you can extend this solution to support arbitrary length bitsets, as long as they are small enough to be converted to an unsigned long:

```
template<size_t sz> struct bitset_comparer {
    bool operator() (const bitset<sz> &b1, const bitset<sz> &b2) const {
        return b1.to_ulong() < b2.to_ulong();
    }
};
map <bitset<8> , int, bitset_comparer<8> > mymap;
map <bitset<16> , int, bitset_comparer<16> > mymap16;
```

Comment: Note: `to_ulong` only works if an `unsigned int` may hold the result, and `unsigned int` is only ever guaranteed by the Standard to be at least 16 bits, which is not much.

Comment: Yes, i have pointed that out in the templated solution. Thanks for the clarification anyway.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: to_ulong (as the name suggests) converts to unsigned long, so we have 32 guaranteed bits here.

Comment: @fontanini: Just use the same type as std::bitset does for the size parameter (size_t). You might also prefer to name the struct e.g. bitset_less to emphasize that it is for bitsets specifically. Or you could specialize std::less for bitsets.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: oups right, I slipped there. However it does not change the fundamental issue.

Comment: @Cwan, i missed the size_t parameter. Thanks, i've fixed it.

Comment: @mfontanini What about if an unsigned long is not enough? Maybe if the unsigned long is enough you do not need to use the bitset...

Comment: @uvts_cvs OP's code uses 8 bit bitsets, so converting to an unsigned long is surely enough here. On another situation, you could use another approach.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution would be to simply use an `unordered_map`, if this still meets your requirements.

This could be [`std::unordered_map<bitset<N>, T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) or [`boost::unordered_map<bitset<N>, T>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html), depending on C++ version or [performance considerations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3904221).

This avoids the need for comparison and [may prove faster](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#std-unordered), depending on requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your comparison function. If you assume your `bitset` models an unsigned integral value then the following function will order the `bitset`s in increasing order (and works for any `N`).

```
template <size_t N>
class LessThan { 
public:
   bool operator() (const std::bitset<N> &lhs, const std::bitset<N> &rhs) const 
   { 
      size_t i = N;
      while ( i > 0 ) {
         if ( lhs[i-1] == rhs[i-1] ) {
            i--;
         } else if ( lhs[i-1] < rhs[i-1] ) {
            return true;
         } else {
            return false;
         }
      }
      return false;
   } 
};
```

If you run the following snippet:

```
  const size_t mysz = 10;
  std::map< std::bitset<mysz>, size_t, Less<mysz> > mymap;
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
     mymap.insert( std::make_pair(std::bitset<mysz>(i),i) );
  }
```

You will have this map:

```
mymap[0]    is the pair ((0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), 0)  
mymap[1]    is the pair ((1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), 1)  
mymap[2]    is the pair ((0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), 2)  
mymap[3]    is the pair ((1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), 3)  
mymap[4]    is the pair ((0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), 4)  
mymap[5]    is the pair ((1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), 5)  
mymap[6]    is the pair ((0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), 6)  
mymap[7]    is the pair ((1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), 7)  
mymap[8]    is the pair ((0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0), 8)  
mymap[9]    is the pair ((1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0), 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will allow map<bitset<N>,int> stuff **directly**:

```
namespace std{
    template<size_t N>
    struct less<bitset<N> > : binary_function <bitset<N>,bitset<N>,bool>{
        bool operator()(const bitset<N> &L, const bitset<N> &R) const{
            for(unsigned int i=0;i<L.size();i++)
                if(L.test(i)){
                    if(!R.test(i))return false;
                }else{
                    if(R.test(i))return true;
            }
            return false; //same
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For storing in the map you can convert bitset to string for large bitset if it's not convertible to u_long and for updating you can change back to bitset and do your changes and store back as a string.

```
map<string , int> mymap;
bitset<N> mybs("10100"); // converting string to bitset
map[mybs.to_string()] = 34; // bitset to string for map
```

This is valid as long as you don't care about the comparison.