# Compare int and bitset in c++

Tags: c++, bitset

How can I compare bitset with an integer ? Or more generally work with integer operator:
something like this :

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
bitset<4> _b1 = 3 ; 


if(_b1>=2 )
    cout<<_b1;



system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: You shouldn't use variable names that start with `_`; they are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain [No, they're not](http://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/241631); that only applies to global namespaces. For local variables the name must begin with an underscore and be followed by an uppercase character (or another underscore) for it to be reserved by the implementation.

Comment: @Praetorian I usually don't like being wrong, but in this case, I'll give in to the fact that I'll forget those intricacies by tomorrow and go back to not using any variable that starts with `_`.

Comment: @Praetorian: I like the 'no _' rule better, regardless of whether or not it's true. It's simpler and easier to remember and doesn't cause me to wonder if a name is in a global namespace or not. And code conforming to it will not run afoul of the more complex rule, nor will it cause people to wonder if the more complex rule is being violated or if they're remembering it right.

Comment: The second answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9702315/1084416) has a nice implementation for comparing `bitset`s.

Comment: @Praetorian - names that contain two consecutive underscores **anywhere**, not just at the beginning, are reserved.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes, of course. The answer I linked to says as much, but I didn't notice my wording was kinda ambiguous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`std::bitset<N>::to_ulong()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_ulong):

```
if(_b1.to_ulong() >= 2)
```

Comment: This only works for small enough bitsets, otherwise you get an exception.

Comment: @PeterWood: Which is also mentioned in the linked reference ;). An exception safe version which uses `to_ulong()` or `to_ullong()` or an additional `bitset` (depending on the right hand side and `N`, using `std::enable_if`) isn't that hard to write, I leave that as an exercise to the OP.

Comment: I know it's in the reference, I'm just trying to avoid cache misses (c:

Answer (score 1):

There is a method `to_ulong` of bitset that returns the value of a `bitset` as `unsigned long`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `to_ulong` to get the unsigned int value of the bitset:

```
 _b1.to_ulong()
```

Here is the [ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/to_ulong/). In your case it would:

```
if(_b1.to_ulong()>=2 )
   cout<<_b1;
```

Also you should avoid [system("pause")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the to_ulong(), and compare to a long, or possibly convert the ulong to an int.