# Search in sorted array with few comparisons

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, sorting

You are given a `std::vector<T>` of distinct items. which is already sorted.
type `T` only supports *less-than* `<` operator for comparisons. and it is a heavy function. so you **have to** use it as few times as possible.

Is there any better solution than a binary search?
If not, is there any better solution than this, that uses less-than operator fewer times?

```
template<typename T>
int FindKey(const std::vector<T>& list, const T& key)
{
    if( list.empty() )
        return -1;

    int left = 0;
    int right = list.size() - 1;
    int mid;

    while( left < right )
    {
        mid = (right + left) / 2;
        if( list[mid] < key )
            left = mid + 1;
        else
            right = mid;
    }

    if( !(key < list[left]) && !(list[left] < key) )
        return left;    

    return -1;
}
```

It's not a real world situation, just a coding test.

Comment: If your code is working, this question may be better placed at [Code Review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Mehrdad Momeny There are already standard algorithms like  std::binary_search, std::lower_bound, std::upper_bound, and std::equal_range.

Comment: Do you allow onetime preprocessing? What about increased memory?

Comment: I guess the main concern is using the less-than operator as few times as possible. Then @arekolek's idea seems interesting. Though I should check how does unordered map search for the key?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I guess i'm not supposed to use those functions. It was a coding quiz, that's the reason I'm not sure about this.

Comment: I've added some more details to my answer, maybe they will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could trade off additional *O(n)* preprocessing time to get amortized *O(1)* query time, using a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) (e.g. an [`unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)) to create a [lookup table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table).

Hash tables compute [hash functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Hashing) of the keys and do not compare the keys themselves.

Two keys could have the same hash, resulting in a *collision*, explaining why it's not guaranteed that every separate operation is constant time. [Amortized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis) constant time means that if you carry out *k* operations that took time *t* in total, then the quotient *t/k = O(1)*, for a sufficiently large *k*.

[Live example](http://ideone.com/2FyMUx):

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
 
template<typename T>
class lookup {
  std::unordered_map<T, int> position;
public:
  lookup(const std::vector<T>& a) {
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) position.emplace(a[i], i);
  }
  int operator()(const T& key) const {
    auto pos = position.find(key);
    return pos == position.end() ? -1 : pos->second;
  }
};
```

This requires additional memory also.

If the values can be mapped to integers and are within [a reasonable range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_mapping) (i.e. *max-min = O(n)*), you could simply use a `vector` as a lookup table instead of `unordered_map`. With the benefit of *guaranteed* constant query time.

See also this [answer to "C++ get index of element of array by value"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11379042/1916449), for a more detailed discussion, including an empirical comparison of linear, binary and hash index lookup.

## Update

If the interface of type `T` supports no other operations than `bool operator<(L, R)`, then using the [decision tree model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_model) you can prove a [lower bound for comparison-based search algorithms](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ekrueger/cscB63h/lectures/tut12.txt) to be Ω(log n).

Comment: But then this type should provide a hash function. Something we're not given.

Comment: @Mehrdad For custom types you can provide your own hash functions. [unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/unordered_map) supports this. In the link there's an example custom hash for a key that is a pair of strings. Unless the interface of `T` is really limited to `bool operator<(L, R)`, but it's hard to believe such type would be useful for anything. Can you give the full interface of `T` in your question, or explain how it's practical if there's nothing else?

Comment: As I told Vlad, it wasn't a real world situation, but a coding test. 
There might have been a hash function available, but I didn't ask about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::lower_bound`. It does it with `log(n)+1` comparisons, which is the best possible complexity for your problem.

```
template<typename T>
int FindKey(const std::vector<T>& list, const T& key)
{
  if(list.empty())
    return -1;
  typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator lb =
        std::lower_bound(list.begin(), list.end(), key);
  // now lb is an iterator to the first element
  // which is greater or equal to key
  if(key < *lb)
    return -1;
  else
    return std::distance(list.begin(), lb);
}
```

With the additionnal check for equality, you do it with `log(n)+2` comparisons.

Comment: But OP asked: `Is there any better solution than a binary search?`, which `std::lower_bound` isn't, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

You can use interpolation search in log log n time if your numbers are normally distributed. If they have some other distribution, you can modify this to take your distribution into account, though I don't know which distributions yield log log time.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search

Comment: I think you meant *uniformly distributed* instead of *normally distributed*. Also, something to take into account is that worst case for interpolation search is `O(n)`.

Comment: @arekolek As long as you know the distribution you can get log log n expected time.