# Does MFC CMap have a good performance compared to std::unordered_map or std::map

Tags: c++, mfc, hashmap, unordered-map

Does MFC `CMap` have a good performance compared to `std::unordered_map` or `std::map`, I ask this question because I'm going to start a project in my company, and to accelerate the development I'm going a start with an existing "similar" project but in this last, there is MFC `CMap` (hash table maps) ans I thought that using `std::unordered_map` can maybe increase performances. I didn't find any benchmarks or good articles related to `CMap` on the internet.
Otherwise, with `std::unordered_map` do I have to fix a size for the hash table too like in `CMap` to avoid collisions and performances issues ?

Comment: ***I didn't find any benchmarks or good articles related to CMap on the interne*** Why don't you benchmark both yourself with a dataset similar to what you will use in production on the hardware that you will use in production?

Comment: CMap doesn't have a move support (you have to always pass it as an output parameter because of this if you want to return one from a function) and doesn't display anything useful in a watch window in a debugger. You also have to write code like `CMap<int, const int&, CString, const CString &> map;` instead of `std::unordered_map<int, const CString> map;`. If I were you I wouldn't even consider using of it - but it is up to you.

Comment: drescgerjm, I have done in the past (std::map vs CMap) but I'm not convinced... but If I don't get answers here, I ll do another benchmark (CMaps vs unordered_map).

Comment: Thanks Marian, CMaps are really ugly !

Comment: CMap is an outdated, non-portable horror show. Do us all a favour: use the standard containers and help bury MFC forever.

Comment: I've just down-voted this because the first thing to do when trying to answering questions like this is to have a look at the documentation.

Comment: Haha OK Richard, those ugly stuff (CStrings, LPCSTR, CMaps, POINTERS ARITHMETICS to parse char strings :( ...) are still used in big companies... and If we use good stuff like smart pointers/STL, the produced code is usually (but no always) not accepted !

Comment: Pick between either `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` for new MFC projects. I would stay away from all MFC containers except `CString` --- See also [`std::map` versus `std::unordered_map`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902644/choosing-between-stdmap-and-stdunordered-map)

Comment: @Aminos I understand the problem but idiot software managers need to be educated, otherwise the discipline of software development will be held back by MFC for another 20 years...

Comment: @MarianSpanik: Like any other native object, display in a watch window is controlled through [Natvis visualizers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620914.aspx). A `std::unordered_map` doesn't display any more useful information than a `CMap` would, out of the box. The debugger can be instructed to display useful information and structure for either type.

Comment: @Aminos: Since you got all worked up about the ugliness of `CString`, keep in mind, that `CString` is **the only** true drop-in replacement for `const char*`/`const wchar_t*`. It can be used **anywhere** a `const char*`/`const wchar_t*` is expected, including variable argument lists.

Comment: IInspectable, you're right !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've made pretty simple performance comparison test:

```
int nElements = 1000000;
CMap<int, int, CString, LPCTSTR> MfcHashTable;
MfcHashTable.InitHashTable(nElements);

// CMap insert
DWORD dwStart = ::GetTickCount();
for(int i=0; i<nElements; i++)
{
    CString sBase;
    sBase.AppendFormat(_T("Test String %d"), i);
    MfcHashTable[i] = sBase;
}

DWORD dwMfcMapInsert = ::GetTickCount() - dwStart;

// CMap lookup
CString sValue;

dwStart = ::GetTickCount();
for(int i=0; i<nElements; i++)
{
    MfcHashTable.Lookup(i, sValue);
}
DWORD dwMfcMapLookup = ::GetTickCount() - dwStart;

// std::map insert
std::map<int, CString> StdMap;
dwStart = ::GetTickCount();
for(int i=0; i<nElements; i++)
{
    CString sBase;
    sBase.AppendFormat(_T("Test String %d"), i);
    StdMap[i] = sBase;
}
DWORD dwStdMapInsert = ::GetTickCount() - dwStart;

//std::map lookup
dwStart = ::GetTickCount();
std::map<int, CString>::iterator it;
for(int i=0; i<nElements; i++)
{
    it = StdMap.find(i);
    CString sBase = it->second;
}
DWORD dwStdMapLookup = ::GetTickCount() - dwStart;

// std::unordered_map insert (hash table)
std::unordered_map<int, CString> StdUnordMap;
dwStart = ::GetTickCount();
for(int i=0; i<nElements; i++)
{
    CString sBase;
    sBase.AppendFormat(_T("Test String %d"), i);
    StdUnordMap[i] = sBase;
}
DWORD dwStdUnordMapInsert = ::GetTickCount() - dwStart;

//std::map lookup
dwStart = ::GetTickCount();
std::unordered_map<int, CString>::iterator it1;
for(int i=0; i<nElements; i++)
{
    it1 = StdUnordMap.find(i);
    CString sBase = it1->second;
}
DWORD dwStdUnordMapLookup = ::GetTickCount() - dwStart;

cout << dwMfcMapInsert << endl;
cout << dwMfcMapLookup << endl;

cout << dwStdMapInsert << endl;
cout << dwStdMapLookup << endl;

cout << dwStdUnordMapInsert << endl;
cout << dwStdUnordMapLookup << endl;
```

Here are the results for **1000000 elements** on **Intel Core i5 2.5Ghz 8GB RAM (Lenovo ThinkPad X230):**

```
MFC CMap insert: 1125
MFC CMap lookup: 125
std::map insert: 1406
std::map lookup: 172
std::unordered_map insert: 1578
std::unordered_map lookup: 140
```

So surprisingly the `CMap` is the winner here. It turns out the ugly legacy `CMap` is not that bad after all!

Comment: And if you include the destruction. The CMap is even much faster, because it use memory blocks comparable with a pool allocator. If you look into the construction of the code it seams clear that the MFC Map is "better". ;) Even if it outdated.

Comment: interesting, I've done a benchmark too, I used words from a big txt dictionary file and High performance coutner to measure time, but I did a mistake, for std::unordered_map I used std::string type for the values or keys whereas for CMaps, I used CStrings, so in that case unordered_map beat CMaps (by tens of milliseconds), I ll rewrite my benchmark and I ll took CString for everybody (because I couldn't put a std::string as a value in CMap, I didn't remember why it didn't work)

Comment: I think the test is in `CMap`'s favor because the size is known (`InitHashTable`), it would be much slower if size is large and unknown. Meanwhile `unordered_map` is not taking advantage of `reserve`. Only lookup is faster for `CMap`.

Comment: You're right. The reason I did not use it is because `reserve()` was not implemented in VS2010 for `unordered_map`. Anyways I've implemented reserve as follows: `StdUnordMap.rehash(std::ceil(nElements / StdUnordMap.max_load_factor()));` The results are the following: 1312 for insert, 140 for lookup. A little bit better but still not the best.

Comment: if you rehash the unordered_map with a correct size and use std::string instead of CMaps in the STL container, well you will see that unordered map beats CMap. Mixed marriage between the two different libraries ain't good ! Otherwise, you use sorted keys, so if you put random int values as keys, well first of all, std::map will be the slowest and then the battle will be between unordered_map and the old CMap, and with my benchmark I found that unordred_map using std::string keys is faster than CMaps using CString  keys by 20 - 40 ms for inserting and 3 - 8 ms for look ups.

Comment: But then for the convenience, unordered_map is the best !

Comment: As long as you don't use a pool allocator, the MFC map will beat the unordered_map specially when you have a lot of entries. And when the hash map is just created for a temporary action the destruction phase in deleting all items is not a "short" action.

Answer (score 0):

Well 20 seconds searching for "MFC CMap" found

> Lookup uses a hashing algorithm to quickly find the map element with a
>   key that exactly matches the given key.

So the big-O efficiency will be like `unordered_map`.

Comment: Could down-voters please explain?  The question asked whether CMap had similar performance to `map` or `unordered_map`.  I answered that it will be similar to `unordered_map`.  Why is that a bad answer?