# How to get the prevalance of each number in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, sorting

I want to get the information of how many times each number has repeated in array. I was doing something like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        cin >> x;
        arr[x]++;
    }
```

Then I realized the given number may be large as "521659942". And obviously I can't create an array with that size.

```
arr[x]++;
```

This is not valid. So what should I do to learn prevalance of each number?

Comment: Check its value against the size of the array first.

Comment: Have you seen [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're essentially using arr[x] as a [`std::map<int,int>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/). The index of the array is your key currently, against which you're storing numbers.

Use a `map` and put values in as you find them. Something like:

```
encounteredNumbers[key]++;
```

`std::unordered_map` and `std::map` both work here, [choosing between them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902644/choosing-between-stdmap-and-stdunordered-map)

Comment: Thanks mate it worked but whenever a number is entered which is entered before, it doesn't count the new one I guess. I think multimap is made for this purpose but I couldn't implement it to my code.

map<int, int> intmap;
intmap[x]++;
This works but this does not.


multimap<int, int> intmap;
intmap[x]++;

Comment: The whole thing you've got in your answer can be shortened to just `encounteredNumbers[key]++;`.

Comment: @K.Yazoglu it works, as count() returns 1 if the value has been entered already, and 0 otherwise. This code is just for entering the data. It doesn't count the number of occurrences. You have to do that yourself in a later piece of code.