# Mapping objects as key with unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11, observable

I have a simple Observable class, implementing the observer pattern. This class maps a template type Event to registered observers. This is all fine, though instead of std::map I'd like to use std::unordered_map for performance reasons.

If I change the member variable below to use an unordered_map I get a rather generic error:

```
std::map<Event, std::vector<std::function<void()>>> _observers;
```

> Static_assert failed "the specified hash does not meet the Hash
>   requirements"

My expectation was that std::map and std::unordered_map should be interchangeable. What are the hashing requirements to use unordered_map in this case, and why is it different?

This is my code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

template <typename Event>
class Observable
{
public:
    Observable()=default;

    template <typename Observer>
    void registerObserver(const Event &event, Observer &&observer)
    {
        _observers[event].push_back(std::forward<Observer>(observer));
    }

    template <typename Observer>
    void registerObserver(Event &&event, Observer &&observer)
    {
        _observers[std::move(event)].push_back(std::forward<Observer>(observer));
    }

    void notify(const Event &event) const
    {
        for (const auto& obs : _observers.at(event)) obs();
    }

    /* disallow copying */
    Observable(const Observable&)=delete;
    Observable& operator=(const Observable&)=delete;

private:
    std::map<Event, std::vector<std::function<void()>>> _observers;
};
```

Comment: For [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) you must specialize [`std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) for the key.

Comment: How is this possible with a template type?

Comment: If you look at the existing [standard specializations for library types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash#Standard_specializations_for_library_types) you will see many specialization for classes that are templates. If you look closer at them I'm sure you will figure out how to do it.

Comment: @benjist Same way `operator<` is possible for a template type: it needs to be implemented for the actual concrete type that eventually gets used as a template argument.

Answer (score 6):

`std::map` and `std::unordered_map` are not interchangeable. They are fundamentally different.

std::map is implemented using a self-balanced binary search tree, and to form a BST, you need to define how you want the keys to be compared (They are ordered). For example, the default comparison function in `std::map` is `std::less` or essentially `operator<`. so Your `Event` type must define `operator<` (either a member function or a non-member function). However, You can change the comparison function to others if you want, by specifying the comparison function in the third template argument.

e.g.

```
std::map<Event, std::vector<std::function<void()>>, MyComp<Event>> _observers;
```

And `myComp` can be any suitable function objects(functor, free function, lambda function) with valid signatures.
e.g

```
template <typename Event>
struct MyComp{
    bool operator()(const Event& lhs, const Event& rhs) const {
        ...
    }
};
```

On the other hand, `std::unordered_map` is implemented using a hash table. Just like its name suggested, they are unordered, so they do not need comparison functions to work. But they need to know how to hash a key (the default is `std::hash`) into an unsigned int value(i.e. `size_t`), and how to tell if two keys are the same(the default is `operator==`).

If `Event` is some user defined types, `std::hash<Event>` will not work. As the result, a `std::unordered_map` cannot be created. However, You can apply the same logic as MyComp above, and create a generalized Event hash function object. e.g.

```
template <typename Event>
struct MyHash {
    std::size_t operator()(const Event& key) const {
        ...
    }
};
```

And if you also want to define a generalized equal function(i.e. not using `operator==` of the Event type), You can do the same thing.

```
template <typename Event>
struct MyEqual {
    bool operator() (const Event& lhs, const Event& rhs) const {
        ...
    }
};
```

Then define the `unordered_map` as

```
std::unordered_map<Event, std::vector<std::function<void()>>,
                   MyHash<Event>, MyEqual<Event>> _observers;
```

And of course, the body of `MyHash` and `MyEqual` should be general enough so that it can work for all or most of the `Event` type you want to use.

Answer (score 3):

> Instead of `std::map` I'd like to use `std::unordered_map` for performance reasons.

That's not good enough, `std::unordered_map` is still slow; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30153545/1593077) of mine and the links there.

But there's more: Actually, ***any* general-purpose map structure is wrong for you**, fundamentally and before having considered implementation quality. You see, since you may have **multiple** observers per event, the relevant data structure is a `std::multimap`, or for the unordered case, an [`std::unordered_multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap). I can't speak to the implementation quality, but I would bet it would be faster for you to use `std::unordered_multimap` over an `std::unrodered_map`-of-vectors.

PS - Everything the commenters and @gchen's answer have told you is basically valid for multimap-vs-unordered-multimap as well. You need to specialize `std::hash`, and the two structures' internals are very different.