# Complexity of std::unordered_multiset insert

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, time-complexity, unordered-multiset

Why is the worst case complexity of `std::unordered_multiset` insert is linear? I understand why is that the case for `std::unordered_set` (you have to check that inserted value is not in the set) but for multiset I don't get it. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 5):

The worst case complexity for `std::unordered_multiset::insert()` is linear because:

- Unordered associative containers that support non-unique keys are said to support *equivalent keys*.  When iterating these containers, elements with equivalent keys are adjacent to one another in iteration, forming *equivalent-key groups*.
- Iterator functions require constant amortized time.

For example, consider the case where `5`, `13`, and `13` are inserted into an `unordered_multiset` that has `4` buckets, and `unordered_multiset::key_eq(5, 13)` returns `false`.  In this case, `unordered_multiset::hash_function(5)` returns different hash codes for both `5` and `13`.  Despite having different hash codes, these elements may still be inserted into the same bucket.  If the hash function for an integer returns the integer itself, and the bucket index is the result of the hash code modulus the number of buckets, then:

- Element `5` is hashed to `5`, and with `4` buckets, it is placed in bucket `1`.
- Element `13` is hashed to `13`, and with `4` buckets, it is placed into bucket `1` as well.

While `unordered_set::insert()` checks to prevent duplicates during insertion, `unordered_multiset::insert()` identifies where to insert the element for equivalent-key grouping.  In the worst case, the bucket contains `[5, 13]` when inserting the final `13`, and upon iterating over all elements, the bucket contains `[5, 13, 13]`.  As iteration over all elements occurs, the complexity is linear in `size()`.

It is worth noting that a rehash may occur during `unordered_multiset::insert()`, and `unordered_multiset::rehash()` is specified as having a complexity with an average case linear in `size()` and the worst case is quadratic.  During a rehash, all elements in the original hash table are iterated over and inserted into a new hash table.  As iteration has a complexity linear in `size()`, and as identified above, each insertion has a worse case linear in `size()`, the resulting worst case is `O(size()*size())`.

Comment: This seems to be right but quadratic complexity for rehashing is not obvious. Before the rehash your equal keys are grouped, so you don't need to group them again during rehash and hence you dont't need quadratic complexity. Moreover unordered_set doesn't have groups of equal keys so why its rehash needs quadratic complexity is not obvious too. My assumption that this is done to support open addressing but  I'm not sure.

Comment: @JamesJohnson In order to be standard complaint, an implementation's worst case cannot exceed the worst case specified by the standard.  The implementation is allowed to have its actual worst case be below the upper bound.  The standard specifies complexity requirements on the bucket interface, which become fairly easy to meet with collision chaining and much more difficult to meet with open addressing.  Consider reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21519560/1053968) answer for more details.