# How does std::unordered_map handle collisions?

Tags: c++, c++11, hashmap, unordered-map

`std::unordered_map` guarantees O(1) time search, but how does it manage collision?

[Cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) claims

> Unordered map is an associative container that contains key-value pairs with unique keys. Search, insertion, and removal of elements have average constant-time complexity.

Assuming a situation where all the Hash codes are same, how is the collision handled internally?

My assumption would be totally wrong if the hash code is unique to every key. In that case how is the unique hash code created where there are no collisions at all?

What approach does `std::unordered_map`'s hash function take to guarantee O(1) search?

Comment: The word *average* is important here. The `unordered_map` is amortized constant, not _constant_.

Comment: @TommyAndersen "average" != "amortized".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't guarantee O(1), it's O(1) on average... Worst case it can be O(n) when there are a lot of collisions. Please see link below, for more info:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2771398/5874704

**Update**

Since the question has been edited, and now asks specifically about collisions for `std::unordered_map`, please have a look at the following answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21519560/5874704

> I think we can conclude that all practical implementations of std::unordered_set (or unordered_map) almost certainly use collision chaining. While it might be (just barely) possible to meet the requirements using linear probing or double hashing, such an implementation seems to lose a great deal and gain nearly nothing in return.

Answer (score 3):

There was an omission from your post that is crucial to understand: `std::unordered_map` has ***average-case*** `O(1)` search. It can take up to `O(n)` in the number of elements in the map to retrieve the element.

As for which hash function it uses - this is up to the user. By default it uses [`std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash).

The only requirement on the hashing function with respect to collision handling is

> Hash functions are only required to produce the same result for the same input within a single execution of a program; this allows salted hashes that prevent collision DoS attacks. (cppreference)

Comment: Please explain the downvote. I can't learn anything if there's no feedback.

Comment: (Not my downvote) It's not amortized, it's average. "Amortized" implies a guarantee.

Comment: @T.C. I guess I'd been operating under the wrong assumption for awhile. :) Edited. Thanks for the note!

Answer (score 1):

> std::unordered_map guarantees O(1) time search, but how does it manage collision?

It uses open addressing / separate chaining, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31113618/410767).

> Cppreference claims
>
> Unordered map is an associative container that contains key-value pairs with unique keys. Search, insertion, and removal of elements have average constant-time complexity.
>
> Assuming a situation where all the Hash codes are same, how is the collision handled internally?

The colliding elements are added into another container holding all values that hashed to that bucket.  That container is usually a linked list, but there's nothing stopping an implementation using e.g. a binary tree.

> My assumption would be totally wrong if the hash code is unique to every key. In that case how is the unique hash code created where there are no collisions at all?

unordered_map isn't required or expected to do anything special to avoid collisions.  (Hash codes being *"unique to every key"* doesn't suffice anyway, as collisions can be created when hash codes are masked or mod-ed into the number of buckets.)

> What approach does std::unordered_map's hash function take to guarantee O(1) search?

This is the crux of your misunderstanding.  unordered_map has O(1) performance when the hash function does an adequate job of hashing the keys across the buckets.  It may degrade to O(n) if the hash function is poor, or has been deliberately targeted by a malicious input of keys known to hash to the same bucket.  The Standard does not require implementations to prevent that, but users can supply a cryptographic hash, pick a hash function from a family at runtime, or otherwise make it impractical for a malicious user - or similar inputs generally - to create many more collisions.

Comment: if it uses a binary tree, it would nOt be any different than std::map(ordered) , as this uses binary tree , which guarantees o(log n) and i this is the major difference between ordered_map and unordered_map(Link List with amortized constant time and O( Log n ) ). correct me if iam wrong

Comment: @user2256825: correction coming up ;-) - unordered_map may use a list or binary tree for values *hashing to the same bucket* - that shouldn' t be confused with a map that *only* has a binary tree and not the hash table / buckets step.  You might find my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30567466/410767) useful as it illustrates the division between the hash table and the logical container (it illustrates a linked list) storing (possible multiple colliding) elements at each bucket.

Comment: Can you elaborate please?  :)

Comment: @user2256825: was that request from before or after I mentioned my linked answer?

Comment: Before :) the linked answer

Comment: i understood how linked list is used when a collision happens , but my confusion was how unordered map may use both link list and binary test as per your comment above. If there is a collision either binary tree is used to store values or a linked list , how can both be used in unordered map.

Comment: @user2256825 it doesn't need to use both, and in practice all C++ implementations I've looked at use linked lists, but there's nothing in the Standard requiring that.  FWIW, some Java implementations use trees.  Re "as per [my] comment above" - what did I say that caused this confusion?  I've reread what I've written above and couldn't spot anything....

Comment: Probably I got confused with this.   Unordered tree may use list or a binary tree for hashing values to same bucket .... And I still did not get this

Comment: I don't see how you can use a tree when you don't have a way of ordering the items.

Comment: @As per my understanding , tree may be used at a specific index of an array where the collision might have taken place , and the index can be a mod of array size  or might have some logic to find an index of an array and during collision either a binary tree or a linked list may be used .bur I dint really understand what is way of ordering .. Is that the hash function logic ? Can you please elaborate

Comment: Step 1 : find an index using a hash function           Step:2 : create a tree at that particular  and insert element(key,value)                                                     If collision happens after step 1  , new element is inserted in the same index's binary tree.     What excatly is way of ordering here

Comment: @T.C. you could order by the hash value (but then need a "multimap" style tree accommodating same-hash entries), or use SFINAE to see if there's a member `operator<`, but that might be a bit dodgy given there's no requirement on the value type requiring the usual semantic meaning of `<`.

Comment: @user2256825: as I mention to T.C. above, and you suggest yourself above, the hash value could indeed be the basis of ordering within a tree.

Comment: Ah, OK, handle the case where different hashes are mapped to the same container, but not when different keys have same hash.

Comment: @T.C. exactly; the former will usually be massively more common with any good hash function....