# C++ std::unordered_map fastest way to insert new element only if it doesn't exist

Tags: c++, performance, c++20

I have an `unordered_map` storing large objects:

`std::unordered_map<uint64_t, LargeObject> map;`

`LargeObject` is an array of POD/there are no pointer members.

I am receiving a lot of `LargeObject`s, so I only want to insert them in the map if they don't already exist (there will be a lot of times they do already exist, as I am listening to multiple sources).

Performance matters, as I am receiving millions.

There seem to be several ways of doing this:

```
map[key] = largeObject;
```

or:

```
map.insert(std::make_pair<uint64_t, LargeObject>(key, largeObject);
```

or:

```
if(map.count(key) == 0)
{
    map[key] = largeObject;
}
```

or:

```
auto iter = map.find(key);
if(iter == map.end())
{
    map[key] = largeObject;
}
```

There maybe more I haven't included.

Which is the most efficient technique to insert when the map's value is a large object?

Comment: Try [this function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace). It adds only if value not existed. Also it constructs object in place so move constructor will be used well. It is fastest way to insert.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what [`try_emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/try_emplace) is for. The API is set up in such a way as to avoid constructing nodes, or even the value, unless it's strictly necessary. It comes form [N4279](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4279.html).

In your case, that would be:

```cpp
auto [it, success] = map.try_emplace(key, largeObject);
```

---

Each of the four options in the OP has issues:

- `map[key] = largeObject` doesn't actually do what you're asking for, it would overwrite the existing item. And even if it wasn't there, it requires default construction and copy assignment.
- The approaches with `count` and `find` both require two lookups.
- `map.insert(std::make_pair<uint64_t, LargeObject>(key, largeObject));` is a single lookup but requires constructing the large object, and the pair, unconditionally.

Not mentioned in the OP is another option: `map.emplace(key, largeObject);` This has the issue that it's actually under-specified whether or not the `pair` is created in the case that the `key` exists. It does on some implementations. The motivation for `try_emplace` was to properly specify the API so that the `pair` *definitely does not* get created if the `key` already exists.

Comment: Will `emplace()` create pair unconditionally?

Comment: @Slava It's kind of under-unspecified (on some implementations it does), hence `try_emplace`.

Answer (score 1):

If "Performance matters", and the map is large don't use `std::unordered_map`, since it is [known to be quite slow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42588384/1593077); and you are barking up the wrong tree w.r.t. insertion.

Here's a by-now-old SO question suggesting several alternatives:

[Super high performance C/C++ hash map (table, dictionary)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300525/super-high-performance-c-c-hash-map-table-dictionary)

Of course, you will need to choose something that fits your workload best.

Additionally - if your objects are large, it is probably better to avoid a map structure templated over the actual large object - since that usually guarantees you will at least have to copy it when inserting into the map; and you don't want to have to copy large objects. Use some kind of reference type (e.g. a pointer, or some numeric index usable to get the address of the large object), and have your hasher dereference that.